# Using vi/vim to insert word between multiple lines

Tags: xml, sed, vi

I have a XML, and I would like to search and match string on multiple lines:

```
</head>
<head>
```

The idea is to eventually insert

```
</head>
</body>
<body>
<head>
```

I think this is doable with vi, I researched a bit and found "_s", but it doesn't seem to work with multiple lines.. This is what I tried:

```
/<\/head>\_s<head>
```

Can someone help?

Comment: The pattern you've provided works for me and highlights </head><head> even when there is a new line in between

Comment: It says E486: Pattern not found: /<\/head>\_s<head>... Does it matter if they're tabbed?? \t</head>\n\t<head> ?

Comment: Yes it matters. Make that <\/head>\\_s*<head> to match multiple newlines, tabs, spaces etc

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you provided works as expected:

```
<head>
</head>
<head>
</head>
<head>
</head>

:%s/<\/head>\_s<head>/<\/head>\r<body>\r<\/body>\r<head>/gc
# remove c

<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<head>
</head>
```